# How to make PDF output and code output look right in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, reproducible-research

I'm working with a large collection of R Markdown files that are collectively used to create a book (PDF output) using `bookdown`. For long lines of code (that will show up in the book), I've been writing it out close to column 80, at which point I insert a hard line break, tab (4 spaces) over, and continue the code. This is what I think looks good in the text (for readers). However, I'm running into problems when this is (for example) part of a `ggplot()` function. Here's a quick (meaningless) example:

```
testx <- seq(1:100)
testy <- rnorm(testx)
testdat <- as.data.frame(cbind(testx, testy))
g <- ggplot(testdat, aes(x = testx/100, y = testy))
g <- g + geom_point() + geom_line()
g <- g + labs(title = "The Posterior Distribution",
    caption = "The mode and 95% HPD intervals are the dot and horizontal line at 
    the bottom, respectively.",
    x = expression(beta[1]~(slope)))
g
```

In this example, I need to break the `caption()` argument across two lines because it is long, but I do NOT want it to break in the actual caption.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use paste0.

```
caption = paste0("The mode and 95% HPD intervals are the dot", 
          " and horizontal line at the bottom, respectively.")
```

Comment: If you would have smacked me on the forehead, I would have appreciated it. Thanks!

Comment: I can still do it mate :)

Comment: If I could upvote your smack more than once, I would! Cheers!